Does the following always hold in the definite integral case?
On an interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ suppose we are computing the integral $$\int_{a}^{b}f(g(x)) \mathrm{d}x.$$
If this integral is finite, then what we can say about $g(x)$? Is $g(x)$ also finite for all $x \in [a,b]$? I am not getting any counter-examples or any way to see if it is true or not.
More precisely, if I take a convex function $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ satisfying:

$f(x)=0$ if and only if $x=0$,
$\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty}$ and
$\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0}$.

What can we say in this case, and also in the general case?

If the integral:
$$\int_a^bf(g(x))\,dx$$
Does not diverge, we can say nothing about $g(x)$. It can still have singularity points in $[a,b]$. Its integral over $[a,b]$ could diverge.
An example? Take the function $g(x)=|\frac1x|$. Its integral between $-1$ and $1$ clearly diverges. But if we take $f(x)=\frac1x$, then $f(g(x))=|x|$ (except at $x=0$), that is:
$$\int_{-1}^1f(g(x))\,dx = 1$$
If we chose $f(x)=x$ we would have:
$$\int_{-1}^1f(g(x))=+\infty$$

A priori the value of the integral does not impose a big restriction on $g$. Since the integral does not change when modifying the integrand on a measure-zero set (null set), you may find that your function $g$ can possess countably infinitely many singularities.
Proof.
Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Then, $$\mu(\mathbb{Q})=\mu \left( \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{q\} \right) = \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \mu(\{q\}) = \sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} 0 = 0$$. The fact that you can change the function accordingly without modifying the value of your integral then follows from its additivity $\int_a^b f\mathrm{d}\mu = \underbrace{\int_{[a;b] \cap \mathbb{Q}}f\mathrm{d}\mu}_{=0} + \int_{[a;b] \setminus \mathbb{Q}}f\mathrm{d}\mu$.
Example.
To give you a simple example for a function $g$ that has one singularity, and respecting your constraint of a convex monotonically increasing function $f:[0;\infty)\to[0;\infty)$, let us consider
$$f(x) = x^2$$
and
$$g(x) = \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}.$$
Then, $g(x)=\frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x-2}$ has an isolated singularity at $x=2$ and its graph looks like the straight line $y=x+2$ with a "hole" at $x=2$. We then verify
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b f(g(x))\mathrm{d}x
&= \int_a^b \frac{(x-2)^2(x+2)^2}{(x-2)^2} \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_a^b (x+2)^2 \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{a+2}^{b+2} u^2 \mathrm{d}u \\
&= \frac{b (12 + 6 b + b^2) - a (12 + 6 a + a^2)}{3} \\
&< \infty
\end{align*}
$$
although $g$ is not defined at $x=2$.

If the integral is finite then $g(x)$ need not to be finite $\forall x\in [a,b]$.If we take $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and
$$g:[0,1]\to \Bbb R\\
g(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac 1x &\text{if} & \frac 1x\in\Bbb N \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
and if we take $f(x)$ as constant function i.e $f(x)=c$ then in this case $$\int_{a}^{b}f(g(x))dx=c$$ which is finite but $g(x)$ is not finite $\forall x\in [a,b]$.

The OP asks for conditions on $f$ that a constant function does not satisfy,

This perfectly suits for first part of question.
